# Can I count on sizeof(string) or sizeof any STL container?

Tags: c++, stl

I have

```
string email_list[] = {"aaa@sds.com", "bbb@sdsds.com"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(email_list)/sizeof(email_list[0]); i ++) {
   ...
}
```

I saw an interesting thing: the `sizeof(email_list[0])` return 28 on debug mode of VS2012; however it gives 24 in release mode. But the `sizeof(email_list)/sizeof(email_list[0])` always gives the correct value -- `2`. So not sure if this is the correct and reliable way to loop through such an array?

How about for other STL containers such as `vector`, `map` ...?

Comment: you would ask STL containers via `.size()`

Comment: In the near future, the generic method that will work on arrays and containers is `size(arr)` or `size(cont)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) will always recover the number of elements in the fixed size array arr for any type.

But be careful; it does not work if arr has decayed into a pointer.

arr[0] is always defined since zero length arrays are not legal in C++.

As for the size of the string being different between debug and release: that's permissible since the standard does not mandate a size for that object. You'll probably find that the debug version has a typed pointer to help debugging.

Answer (score 4):

```
sizeof(array_name)/sizeof(array_name[0])
```

Will always be the size of the array as

```
sizeof(array_name) = sizeof(array_name[0]) * number of elements in array_name
```

Different compilers/builds may change the value of `sizeof(array_name[0])` but it will always work.

One thing you can do is use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which will iterate through all of the elementes without you having to specify the size

```
for (const auto & e : email_list)
    //...
```

This works for all arrays and for all types the have `begin` and `end` member or free functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine how many entries are in a container, then do not use sizeof.  That tells you the size of the control block that manages the container.

Use the size() method to determine the number of entries in an stl container.

Note that this answer applies to the title of this question.  In the body of the question you have an array of strings.   An array is an object inherited from C.  The sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) technique works to determine the number of strings in the array, but it does NOT work to determine the number of characters in the string (or to determine the number of entries in any other STL container.)

Comment: Neither `.length()` or `.count()` exist on the containers OP asked about. They want `.size()`

Comment: (Well `.count()` exists for map, but for an entirely different purpose)

Comment: In my original answer I used "count" where I meant "size" (sorry I've been coding in C# recently.), but fixed it with an (almost) immediate edit.  I'll stand by the answer the way it reads now.

Comment: That's fair I suppose. I would still argue against `.length()`, however. I would not consider `std::string` (the only thing I can think of that has such a method) to be a [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), although it can be treated as one.

Comment: he asked about string.  `length` works there, but so does `size` so I'll remove `length` from my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndyG Get ready for C++17: [basic.string] `A basic_string is a contiguous container (23.2.1).`

Answer (score 0):

> I saw an interesting thing: the sizeof(email_list[0]) return 28 on debug mode of VS2012; however it gives 24 in release mode.

the reason, at least under Visual Studio is that in debug mode, macro definition `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is set to value 2, this enables iterator checks which apparently requires adding 4 bytes to string class. If you set `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` in preprocessor definitions then in debug you will have sizeof(std::string)==24.

There are lots of other differences between release and debug modes, you might finish your project, and have it run successfully under debug build for hours, and then run it under Release and have immediate crash. Most if not all of this errors are results of undefined behaviour in code.

> sizeof(email_list)/sizeof(email_list[0])

this will always give you number of elements in array so you are safe to use it as a count in both debug and release builds.

> How about for other STL containers such as vector, map ...?

[vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) has a size() function for getting number of elements (same value for both builds - unless some macro changes that) and [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/size/) also provides size() function. But you usually iterate map with iterators.